# Is it possible to track the activity of deploy keys (a log of when someone pulled/fetched)?

Tags: git, github

I'm creating a program that will be used by a few people and I want to assign to each of them their own deploy key, which will be used for automatic updates. I would like to have a log of when someone used the key to pull/fetch an update from github. Is this possible?

So far all I've found is this deploy key manager on github website in project settings, where you can see if the key was used recently.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Github API docu only lists deploy key's creation, deletion and update as audited events. Second guess would have been to create a webhook on pull, but this one is not audited as well.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that could be the case :/